# C# basic Math, want to use decimals sometimes

Tags: c#, math

I've got 3 text boxes and I want to use decimals sometimes for an example:

```
box1 3.5
box2 30
box3 12.56
```

and this is the current code I'm using that only works with integer

```
int box1 = int.Parse(Number1TextBox.Text);
int box2 = int.Parse(Number2TextBox.Text);
int box3 = int.Parse(Number3TextBox.Text);

int answer = box1 * box2 * box3;

AnswerLabel.Text = "The answer is"+ answer.ToString();
```

Comment: So why don't just use decmals and `Decimal.Parse` instead of ints if you need decimals?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: _" i want to use decimals"_ so why don't you use [them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers don't have fractions. Use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) if you want reliable numeric values with decimals.

```
decimal box1 = decimal.Parse(Number1TextBox.Text);
decimal box2 = decimal.Parse(Number2TextBox.Text);
decimal box3 = decimal.Parse(Number3TextBox.Text);

decimal answer = box1 * box2 * box3;
```

You can round back the result like this:

```
decimal rounded = Math.Round(answer);
```

Comment: This one worked great! now i just want the answer will be in whole numbers and rounded up. and i want to put a text behind the answer example the answer is 30 €

Comment: Use Math.Round to round numbers msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx and to add the euro sign in your string do : "your string"+"€"

Comment: You can use `Math.Round` for the rounding. The last part of your comment, well, give it a try.

Comment: thanks! but where in the code do i put it? the decimal rounded = Math.Round(answer);

Comment: @RasmusJosefsson - Oh come on, now you're just being too lazy. You need to learn how to figure the very basic of basic stuff out on your own. SO is here to guide you in the right direction, but it's not a tutorial site and it's also not the place write all the code for you.

Answer (score -1):

First of you are parsing the strings into integers which are just that integers, full numbers first you need to do something like this:

```
    double box1 = double.Parse(Number1TextBox.Text);
    double box2 = double.Parse(Number2TextBox.Text);
    double box3 = double.Parse(Number3TextBox.Text);

    double answer = box1 * box2 * box3;


    AnswerLabel.Text = "The answer is"+ answer.ToString();
```

The next thing you need to look out for is localization, some country allow , as a decimal delimiter some only allow a .

Comment: Doubles are less reliable since it is a floating point numeric.